# Convert keys of a nested dictionary to upper case

Tags: python, string, dictionary, for-loop, dictionary-comprehension

Have a dictionary:

```
data = {'Common': {'height': 165, 'weight': 70, 'measure': ['cm', 'kg']},
         'Man': 'handsome',
         'Woman': {'feature': 'pretty', 'weight': 50},
         'Dog': {'feature': 'barks', 'height': 10, 'weight': 20}}
```

Would like to convert only dictionary keys to UPPERCASE.

Tried the following code:

```
d = {}
d1 = {}
for k, v in data.items():
    if isinstance(v, dict):
        for i, j in v.items():
            d1[i.upper()] = j
        d[k.upper()] = d1
    else:
        d[k.upper()] = v

print(d)
```

...which produces the output with unnecessary keys and height and weight rationalization as follows:

```
{'COMMON': {'HEIGHT': 10, 'WEIGHT': 20, 'MEASURE': ['cm', 'kg'], 'FEATURE': 'barks'}, 
    'MAN': 'handsome', 
  'WOMAN': {'HEIGHT': 10, 'WEIGHT': 20, 'MEASURE': ['cm', 'kg'], 'FEATURE': 'barks'}, 
    'DOG': {'HEIGHT': 10, 'WEIGHT': 20, 'MEASURE': ['cm', 'kg'], 'FEATURE': 'barks'}}
```

My expected output is:

```
{'COMMON': {'HEIGHT': 165, 'WEIGHT': 70, 'MEASURE': ['cm', 'kg']},
 'MAN': 'handsome',
 'WOMAN': {'FEATURE': 'pretty', 'WEIGHT': 50},
 'DOG': {'FEATURE': 'barks', 'HEIGHT': 10, 'WEIGHT': 20}}
```

1. Where am I going wrong?
2. What is the correct dictionary comprehension like `{{i.upper(): j} if isinstance(j, dict) else {k.upper(): v} for k, v in data.items() for i, j in v.items()}`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue with your code is that you are reassigning `d1` if the value is a dictionary. You can solve this by using [`copy.deepcopy()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/copy.html#copy.deepcopy):

**Code:**

```
from copy import deepcopy

d = {}
d1 = {}
for k, v in data.items():
    if isinstance(v, dict):
        for i, j in v.items():
            d1[i.upper()] = j
        d[k.upper()] = deepcopy(d1)
    else:
        d[k.upper()] = v
```

**Output:**

```
>>> d
{'COMMON': {'HEIGHT': 165, 'WEIGHT': 70, 'MEASURE': ['cm', 'kg']},
 'MAN': 'handsome',
 'WOMAN': {'FEATURE': 'pretty', 'WEIGHT': 50},
 'DOG': {'FEATURE': 'barks', 'HEIGHT': 10, 'WEIGHT': 20}}
```

**Alternatively, as a dictionary comprehension:**

```
>>> {k.upper(): {i.upper(): j for i, j in v.items()} if isinstance(v, dict) else v for k, v in data.items()}
{'COMMON': {'HEIGHT': 165, 'WEIGHT': 70, 'MEASURE': ['cm', 'kg']},
 'MAN': 'handsome',
 'WOMAN': {'FEATURE': 'pretty', 'WEIGHT': 50},
 'DOG': {'FEATURE': 'barks', 'HEIGHT': 10, 'WEIGHT': 20}}
```

Comment: Why is [deepcopy](https://docs.python.org/3/library/copy.html#copy.deepcopy) not needed in dictionary comprehension?

Comment: @reservoirinvest because instead of creating a dictionary called `d1` using a for-loop, and then pairing it with the original key, we are building it using a nested dictionary-comprehension, so we never assign it to a variable.

Comment: @reservoirinvest you could remove `deepcopy` from the original if you used `d[k.upper()] = {i.upper(): j for i, j in v.items()}` after `if isinstance(v, dict):`.

Answer (score 3):

You can do something like that, copy to other `dict` with required keys:

```
data = {'Common': {'height': 165, 'weight': 70, 'measure': ['cm', 'kg']},
        'Man': 'handsome',
        'Woman': {'feature': 'pretty', 'weight': 50},
        'Dog': {'feature': 'barks', 'height': 10, 'weight': 20}}
data2 = {}
for k in data.keys():
    data2[k.upper()] = data[k]
```

UPDATE:
If you want to change not only keys on Level 1, you should use the recursive function:

```
data = {'Common': {'height': 165, 'weight': 70, 'measure': ['cm', 'kg']},
        'Man': 'handsome',
        'Woman': {'feature': 'pretty', 'weight': 50},
        'Dog': {'feature': 'barks', 'height': 10, 'weight': 20}}

def keys_to_upper(dict1):
    dict2 = {}
    for k in dict1.keys():
        if isinstance(dict1[k], dict):
            dict2[k.upper()] = keys_to_upper(dict1[k])
        else:
            dict2[k.upper()] = dict1[k]
    return dict2

d2 = keys_to_upper(data)
```

Answer (score 1):

**List comprehension** is faster because it is optimized for the Python `interpreter` to spot a predictable pattern during `looping`. Besides the syntactic benefit of `list comprehensions`, they are often as fast or faster than equivalent use of `map` .

```
data = {'Common': {'height': 165, 'weight': 70, 'measure': ['cm', 'kg']},
        'Man': 'handsome',
        'Woman': {'feature': 'pretty', 'weight': 50},
        'Dog': {'feature': 'barks', 'height': 10, 'weight': 20}}

    for k, v in data.items():
      if isinstance(v, dict):
        data[k.upper()] = data.pop(k)
```

**output>**

```
data = {'COMMON': {'height': 165, 'weight': 70, 'measure': ['cm', 'kg']},
        'Man': 'handsome',
        'WOMAN': {'feature': 'pretty', 'weight': 50},
        'DOG': {'feature': 'barks', 'height': 10, 'weight': 20}}
```